# ¿Cómo modificar, dentro de una clase abstracta, el valor asociado a un atributo en tiempo de ejecución?

Tags: java, reflection

Tengo la siguiente estructura, donde hay una clase abstracta con un atributo `baseDirectory` de forma predeterminada.

```
public abstract class PerformanceTest {
/**
* Base directory.
*/
private String baseDirectory = "C:/msg-inbox/";
```

...

Por otro lado, hay una clase que extiende de la clase abstracta.

```
public class MessagePerformanceTest extends PerformanceTest {
/**
* Constructor.
*/
public MessagePerformanceTest() {
}
```

...

Finalmente tengo una clase principal como esta:

```
public class MessagesMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Field field = PerformanceTest.class.getDeclaredField("baseDirectory");
          field.setAccessible(true);
          field.set(null,args[0]);

    MessagePerformanceTest messagePerformanceTest = new MessagePerformanceTest();
    messagePerformanceTest.createMessages();
```

...

El problema con el que me encuentro es que no sé la mejor manera de pasar el atributo de `baseDirectory` como un argumento porque necesito cambiar este valor en tiempo de ejecución. Estoy tratando de usar la reflexión, pero no funciona por el momento. **¿Alguien tiene idea de una posible solución?**

Para resumir, necesito cambiar el valor predeterminado `C: / msg-inbox /` a otra cosa similar a `\ folder1 \ test`

Comment: Este es stackoverflow en español...

Comment: this site is in spanish. You could try stackoverflow.com instead of es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no está en español.

Comment: Ya está modificado hombre...

Comment: *pero no funciona por el momento*: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Y por qué necesitas usar reflexión? ¿Por qué no agregar una property pública para poder modificar `baseDirectory`? ¿Tienes alguna restricción técnica que te impida cambiar el diseño de las clases? Normalmente, si una variable es privada es que hay una buena razón por la que no deberías tratar de modificarla.

Comment: Hola, la variable podría ser pública, eso no habría problema. Lo de por el momento es que estoy trabajando en ello también en paralelo :P. Lo de la property era un plan b pero prefería poder pasar la nueva ruta por línea de comandos ya que estamos pasándole a esa batería de pruebas otros parámetros y para tratar de tenerlo todo unificado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por reflect para que te funcione solo cambia a  esto:

```
MessagePerformanceTest messagePerformanceTest = new MessagePerformanceTest();

Field field = PerformanceTest.class.getDeclaredField("baseDirectory");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(messagePerformanceTest,args[0]);

messagePerformanceTest.createMessages();
```

Esto es debido que los métodos así como los atributos privados le corresponden a la clase padre, por lo que en el class de la hija no puede ser obtenido ese valor, por lo que una vez que tienes el campo de la padre se lo seteas a la hija.

En tu ejemplo el null significa que vas a editar un campo de la clase (estático).

```
field.set(null,args[0]);
```

Comment: Perfecto!, muchas gracias!